# the font changes when I change font size in gVim

Tags: gvim, font

I am sorry if this is a dumb question, I am a beginner in vim.

I am trying to change my font size in gvim, I tried using `set guifont=*`, but only two sizes appears on the list 7 and 11 , and typing any other size seems to change nothing and when I change it to 11 the font changes to another font.

I have to mention that this only happen with `Fixedsys font` and sadly the font I wish to have.

I tried to reinstall gVim and I also tried to change it using vimrc. I tried to reinstall the font and tried it also on NeoVim but nothing worked.

This is before I change the size
[image: This is before I change the size]

This is after I change the size
[image: This is after I change the size]

Comment: They look quite similar to me; perhaps this is the font doing something funny at different sizes (_e.g._, in the smaller one its probably easier to read 0 with a slash; at larger sizes, a dot suffices)?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble They appear the same probably because the picture is small but They clearly look different. In the first picture the font looks sharper and more pixilated and nicer of course.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have seen this font on other devices with other sizes, I don't think the problem is from the font itself rather than my device or my configuration.

Comment: Fixedsys is "fixed". Use another font.